# jQuery for loop only running once despite condiiton

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a small jQuery script that I want to dynamically append divs to a section in my page, based on changes to three select elements.

My php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div>

        <select class="food_counter" id="food_counter1" name="Fruit">
            <option selected>0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>            
        </select>

        <select class="food_counter" id="food_counter2" name="Vegetable">
            <option selected>0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>            
        </select>

        <select class="food_counter" id="food_counter3" name="Dairy">
            <option selected>0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>            
        </select>       

    </div>

    <section id="foods">
        <h2>My Food</h2>
    </section

</body>
```

My js:

```
$(function() {

    $('.food_counter').change(function() {

        n = $('.food_counter').length;

        clearAll();

        for(i=0; i < n; i++) {

            var selector = i + 1;
            var currentOption = $('#food_counter' + selector.toString());
            var currentValue = $('#food_counter' + selector.toString() + ' option:selected').text();
            var multiplier = parseInt(currentValue);

            for(j=0; j < multiplier; j++) {
                addNewSelectors(currentOption.attr("name"));
            }

        }


    });

});

function clearAll() {
    $('.new_food').remove();
}

function addNewSelectors(id) {

    var options = ["One", "Two", "Three"];

    $('#foods').append("<div class='new_food'><p>" + id + "</p><select>");

    for(i=0; i < options.length; i++) {
        $('#foods select').append($("<option/>").attr("value", i).text(options[i]));
    }   

    $('#foods').append("</select></div>");

}
```

My outer for loop in my js script seems to be behaving strangely. If I change the counter `food_counter1` to 2, it behaves correctly - appending two divs to `#foods`.

But if I try to change, say, `food_counter1` to 1, and `food_counter2` to 2, it only appends a single instance of `Fruit` to `#foods`, instead of three divs (Fruit, Vegetable, Vegetable).

Upon closer inspection, it seems like my outer for loop only runs once, despite `n` always being 3. Strangely, if I reset the counter that fired the `change` function to 0, the loop will continue to run.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Ehh - I dont think you can append HTML in chunks like that - have you tried creating the entire `select` element and then appending to that?

Comment: I have, and I run into the same problem. I think I actually can append in chunks like what I'm doing now, since setting `food_counter1` to 3 appends divs in the way that I want to, it's just the behaviour of my loop that I can't figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable "i" used in the for loops is not specifically defined but simply used, and is therefore considered a "global". To fix it, you can rewrite your for loops as:

```
for(var i=0; i < n; i++) { ...
```

and then inside your addNewSelectors like

```
for(var i=0; i < options.length; i++) {...
```

This will declare i in the local scope of the block/function.